# android тени для customview невыпуклой формы

Tags: java, android, customview

Я определяю форму для тени моего customview следующим способом:

```
view.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
            @Override
            public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                outline.setConvexPath(bg);
                outline.setAlpha(1);
            }
        });
```

проблема заключается в том, что мой customview невыпуклой формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а метод outline.setConvexPath() принимает только выпуклые формы, из-за чего я не могу поставить тень

Comment: Если вы используете API21+ то вам стоит использовать параметр elevation: https://www.fandroid.info/urok-4-android-material-design-ustanovka-tenej-i-obrezka-view/, https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping

Comment: @Valeriy, это customview, одним выставлением значения elevation тут не получится отделаться т.к. elevation это грубо говоря высота, на которой располагается view, но, пока я не укажу границы для тени, тень ее не будет отображаться